# Use of _id for document identifier in elastic search

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have a document with _id as a parameter. I have the below JSON

```
{  
   "_id":{  
      "$oid":"52af48b5d55148fa0c199643"
   },
   "email":"example.ex@example.com"
}
```

Corresponding Java class:

```
@Document(indexName = "Test")
public class Test {

  @Id
  @ObjectId
  private String _id;

  private String email;
}
```

The conversion of json object is successful but there is a problem in saving the data to elastic search.

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Field [_id] is a metadata field and cannot be added inside a document. Use the index API request parameters
```

I have seen some references and came to a conclusion that i cannot use _id.. But am looking for a way to use a JsonProperty but it also does not work as i guess ObjectId uses JsonProperty internally.

Kindly provide suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message say, you can't use field with name _id inside the document.

To fix that use "replace all"(or function like that that replace substring in other substring) function, and replace all "_id" occurrence with "id"

Comment: Could you please suggest some json adapter to convert in these cases...i cannot change the json format as it comes from an external source

Answer (score 0):

Just use as following

```
{  
     "_id":"52af48b5d55148fa0c199643",
      "email":"example.ex@example.com"
}
```

And remove @ObjectId

Comment: Hi Thank you for your post...I cannot change the json format as it comes from a external source